# how to maintain list of service calls in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I need one help for Angular js.

I need make the 400 service calls when click on button, but it is taking too much time in iPad hybrid application. can any one suggest me how to maintain the service calls.

Now i am using

```
   forEach.array(function(){
here i am making service call.
   });
```

Is there any other way to do this one like main thread or child thread in angular js?

Can you please help me any one.

Comment: Personally 400 calls from a client sound nasty. Why not managing this from a server side facade component?

Comment: Yeah Good, But server side we don't have option to do @AlessandroSantini, Because some other reason server side code will pay money that's reason we are planning to do in client side only. is there any idea to do?

Comment: What are you asking? If you have to do 400 calls you have to do 400 calls. I can't see how there will be anything apart from changing your server to reduce the amount of calls.

Comment: @WayneEllery for example common calls shared between clients could be cached, less mobile bandwidth required (if the iPad is using a 3G connection, for example) - they seem to me two good reasons, aren't they?

Comment: Possibly there is something that could be done, but without specific details as to what the service call is and what the data is used for it's very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called as [angular interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). You can just track the outgoing request from the interceptor to capture the service call being made.

Here is a [tutorial that will explain it to you](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-angularjs-interceptors-with-http).

What you do is essentially in you app.js file push the interceptor service.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(yourservice);
```

This service will contain your logic to capture the request and responses being made. The service is a simple angular service which qul contain the request variable.

```
var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    //the header should contain your request URL's. Identify the ones which are serivce requests and add them to a queue
    return config;
}
```

Comment: @Siva 400 service calls is never a good idea at one go! I would suggest you use the interceptors to paginate your request, wait for the responses, the use deferred queue to send the updates.

Comment: Thank you for good respnose and good solution. thnak you so much.@shouvik

Comment: You are welcome! :) Please accept your responses to elicit more responses to your questions.

Comment: I didn't understand what did you say. can you tell me what i need to do? @shouvik

Comment: @Siva here is an [example](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/). What you need to do is create a method that is capable of intercepting every request. Once you do that, you should be able to create function that will capture these requests and defer them or modify them in some way. This also is a nice way to just watch the requests.